# Nested select with dynamic where

Tags: sql, select, nested, sum

I need to show a current year and previous year to date results. Ideally what I want the results to look like is

```
ID|CYTD|PYTD
# |Sum |Sum
```

And the query that I have looks like below. The problem is how do I set the where to have it match the same id as the line that the current year has.

```
select Table.ID,
 SUM(Table.Column) as CYTD, 

(select SUM(Table.Column) from Table
where Table.Id = ?? and Table.Year between Prev and Current
group by Table.Id) as PYTD

Where Table.Year between Current and Future
group by Table.Id
```

Comment: Can you describe the table? Does it have a Year Column? What datatype  is that column?

Comment: ID int , Amount decimal, Date datetime. Its kind of bigger than that and the query too, so I tried to simplify it to share the bare bones of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
SELECT TT.ID,
    SUM(TT.amount) AS CYTD,
    (SELECT SUM(T.amount)
     FROM YOURTABLE T
     WHERE T.Id = TT.id
        AND T.DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-01-01'
     GROUP BY T.Id) AS PYTD
FROM YOURTABLE TT
WHERE TT.DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY TT.Id
```

Because `yourtable` appears more than once in the query, you have to give it an alias in each appearance and then you compare their id's, and that should give the result you want.

EDIT:

If you want it to be dynamic, and use the current year as a reference, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT TT.ID,
    SUM(TT.amount) AS CYTD,
    (SELECT SUM(T.amount)
     FROM YOURTABLE T
     WHERE T.Id = TT.id
        AND YEAR(T.DATE) = YEAR(now())
     GROUP BY T.Id) AS PYTD
FROM YOURTABLE TT
WHERE YEAR(TT.DATE) = YEAR(now()) - 1
GROUP BY TT.Id;
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7eb84/2) to see it in action.